# Wearable to Wearable communiction

Tags: android, wear-os

is it possible to send data (e.g. a textfile) directly from one android wearable to another wearable - for example via bluetooth? Or is it required to communicate over the two associated handhelds?

Many thanks!
Henriette

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible since Android Wear fully support the Bluetooth library. You may not use the Android Wear Library that for NOW only connect ONE Wearable to ONE Smartphone. 
You need to implement a wearable application managing bluetooth discovery and pairing, then by opening a connection socket you can exchange the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

From the second part of your question, it seems you are referring to two wearable devices that are paired with two separate phones. In that case, there is no connectivity or association between these two devices and you can only achieve communication between them by, say, using the phones and handling the communication over there; that may happen in a variety of ways depending on your requirements